# Git Bash Command Line Drag & Drop Option

Tags: git-bash, git

I used to **drag and drop** folders to **Git Bash command line** to change the working directory or to create new repos, but this option is no longer available for me. I'm using Windows 10 64bit -

I did uninstalled and reinstalled git due to some errors I was experiencing, and after that I can no longer do this **drag and drop** thing.

Any clues about this issue?

Comment: Are you launching the CMD as Admin? See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded to the [latest Git release](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), using [`PortableGit-2.15.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.15.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.15.0-64-bit.7z.exe):

```
C:\tools\gits>rmdir latest

C:\tools\gits>mklink /J latest PortableGit-2.15.0-64-bit
Junction created for latest <<===>> PortableGit-2.15.0-64-bit

C:\tools\gits>git version
git version 2.15.0.windows.1
```

Once I enter a bash session:

```
C:\tools\gits>bash

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

vonc@bvonc MINGW64 ~/Documents
$ git version
git version 2.15.0.windows.1
```

, I can still drag and drop a folder and use the result to change directory:

```
vonc@bvonc MINGW64 /c/tools/gits
$ cd "C:\Users\vonc\Documents"

vonc@bvonc MINGW64 ~/Documents
```

---

Note: as [illustrated in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TF6-_AItK1o), drag&drop will work in application with the same rights. So double-check if you are launching the CMD Windows as Administrator.

The [OP edherroj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8865383/edherroj) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47066547/git-bash-command-line-drag-drop-option/47068061#comment81246143_47068061):

> I updated the settings of Git Bash application and **unchecked the option 'Run this program as Administrator'** and it now allows me to drop folders into the application.

Comment: I updated the settings of Git Bash application and unchecked the option 'Run this program as Administrator' and it now allows me to drop folders into the application. Weird! I thought running a program as admin will give you all privileges but here is not the case. Anyway, thats for your time, I appreciate!